# VB.NET DataGridView on select whole row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a question for the DataGridView in vb.net (making a form).

I have a button that is disabled. This button should only be enabled when a row in this list is marked/selected/highlighted. How can i write this? A doubleclick on the DataGridView gives me

```
Private Sub My_Grid_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles My_Grid.CellContentClick

End Sub
```

This only works on some of the cells and does not do any thing if i click on the * to the left where i select and highlight this row.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: SelectedIndexChange event can be selected as shown]

You need to change the Event name to `Handles My_Grid.SelectedIndexChanged`

So the full Sub would be something like

```
Private Sub My_Grid_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles My_Grid.SelectedIndexChanged
     'Your code that handles this event here.
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me 
"Event 'SelectedIndexChanged' cannot be found."

Comment: Thanks, but still not found. Something i have to import?

Comment: The intellisense helped me out here, "Handles My_Grid.SelectionChanged" did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you are using a different version. Thanks for letting me know